# Blank screen after Expo publish

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I encountered a serious error with expo.

I have developed an app in React Native and, at the time of publication through the *`expo publish`* command, it correctly generates the address where I can scan the QR code, but, once this is done, on my mobile I see the loading screen of the app but a white screen appears after that.

I can't do anything, not even see if it generates any errors or not, it stays blank for more than five minutes (then I closed the app).

With *`npm start`* the app works perfectly for me, so I don't know what the problem could be.
I have searched around on the Internet but it seems that in very few we have encountered this hitch and, in the few cases where this has happened, I have tried to apply the solutions proposed by other users, but nothing has changed.

I don't think about reporting my code: first of all I don't know what to put, as I have no clue as to where the error is and, above all, it would just get in the way.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?